# Cookie consent: Google Adsense code isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, adsense, cookieconsent

I'm trying some cookie consent frameworks like https://www.cookieconsent.com in order to improve the privacy settings at my website. In general those frameworks work in the same way: All `script` tags get a `type="text/plain"` and if the visitor accepts cookie, they change the type to `type="text/javascript"` and execute the code.

However, it doesn't work for Google Adsense tags like

```html
<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="targeting" data-ad-client="XXXX" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

In the Chrome and Safari consoles I can see that the type is `type="text/javascript"` but I don't see ads. It works perfectly for everything else (e.g Google Analytics). What's wrong with the Google Adsense code and how can I show it only to people who like cookies?

Comment: Do you know how they execute the code? By just changing `type="text/plain"` to `type="text/javascript"` I don't see browser actually fetching and executing JS file (network tab is empty).

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau In the network tab I can see that `cookie-consent.js` fetches `https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js` successfully. I guess it executes it with something like `eval()`.

Comment: Not quite, it's using `document.createElement("script");` to append a new script element to `<head>` and changes the attribute to type="text/javascript". Maybe this is the cause why it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841383/10385339

Comment: Then it should work. The question you mention uses `show_ads.js` which indeed won't work with dynamically appended scripts, but `adsbygoogle.js` should work. Do you have a page that reproduces it?

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau Yeah, I get the feeling that the workarounds won't work for the "auto ads" feature because you cannot know where Adsense wants to place ads. I guess only Google can fix it. I can reproduce it on this page: https://www.sparplaene.net The green button "Alle akzeptieren" will allow all cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like cookieconsent JS in addition to insering new `<script>` tag also removes the old tag. And old tag contained `data-ad-client` attribute with your web property code. Without it we `adsbygoogle.js` won't work. So there not much we (Google) can do here as by the time `adbygoogle.js` runs web property is gone from the page. I think it should work if the old script hasn't been removed. If you have any way to contacting cookieconsent.com developers - you should raise this issue there. I can also help if needed.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that! Thx for pointing me to the missing `data-ad-client` attribute. I was able to fix it by adding one line to my `cookie-consent.js`: `null!==t.getAttribute("data-ad-client")&&n.setAttribute("data-ad-client",t.getAttribute("data-ad-client")),`  I just set `data-ad-client` again if it existed before (This is the full file: https://www.sparplaene.net/js/cookie-consent.js). I was trying to contact cookieconsent.com but they don't have any contact information on their website. Smells a bit scammy. Anyways, my ads are finally back :-)